# how to redirect in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, web, express

I'm having some issues with redirecting between directories, the problem is I can manage to redirect to another file in different directory. My directory structure looks like this:

```
-views
  -add_user.jade

-routes
  -index.js
```

I try to redirect to *add*_ *user.jade* from *index.js*, how would you guys do it

```
res.redirect('???');
```

---

If *index.js* in the same directory as **views**, the code below works

```
-index.js
-views
  -add_user.jade

res.redirect('./add_users');
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You want to redirect to the **URL** (not the view name) that you want the user to go to.

For example, if the route `"/user/add"` renders the `"add_user.jade"` view then you want to use

```
 res.redirect("/user/add");
```

Comment: This solution still works for the current Express. See [this](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/5d3d9ecb-8379-4764-9e21-8473386981a7) live Docker example.

Comment: @user7503126's live Docker example isn't live anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can redirect on Url with the help of

```
return res.redirect('/server/Thank');
```

Thank is a view file with `Thank.jade` extension.

and route is `/server/thank`

Answer (score 0):

In Node js `res.setHeader('Location', 'url');`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

first install http if not installed already:

```
yarn add http
```

Then import/require it:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(302,  {Location: "http://www.oddcircles.com"})
    response.end();
}).listen(3030);
```

Answer (score -45):

Try this:

```
document.location.href="full_URL";
```

Comment: The OP is asking about server side JavaScript, while your answer only works in the browser

Comment: And if your suggestion is "Return a 200 response with an HTML document containing some JavaScript that does the redirect" then that is probably the more unreliable, inefficient way to do it … and it also breaks the back button.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes it seems like every person who upvoted the best answer has also cared for this one.

Comment: The document object is a global that is only available for the browsers. In Node you need to use res.redirect.